# How to keep trouser fly up?

Tags: clothing

Some of my trousers can't keep the fly up.
It's annoying and sometimes awkward to get it up, particulary in public.

How can I prevent them from opening while walking?

One solution I already know is to fix it with a paperclip, but then, when I go to the restroom, I have to "unlock" this fixture which is annoying again.